# Does methods have different copies for eact object?

Tags: java

Hi
 I have a class Sample in java.
It has two instance variables and one method to add the instance variable and print the sum.
I created two Objects of Sample class. Its clear to me that both objects will have their own data members.
I have to know that will both the object have one common copy of the method to which both uses or they have different copy in jvm.

Comment: Its a nice question, but why do you *have* to know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the JVM keeps the instructions separate from the data in memory layout, and the "code" of the method is referred to by the object.  This means that two instances calling the same method will generally both reference the same "code" block in the memory layout.

Comment: If two or more object uses the same code block at the same time; does it means that one object will finish its work first then second will use or both objects may work simultaneously with the same code block?

Comment: There is no reason for code to be used exclusively only by one thread, as the Java VM does not support self-modifying code, and so the code is immutable. (It could be modified by the Hotspot optimizer, but you don't have to worry about this.)

Answer (score 1):

The class is loaded once by the JVM.  So there is one common copy of the method in memory.